# LIST programming: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, memory-address

I'm trying to program a list that one of its field has a pointer (or the address) that leads to another list...this is the declaration of the two lists

```
struct etat {

 char e;
 int termin;
 struct etat *etatsuiv;
 struct etat *transi;

 };
struct etat *tete,*p,*q;

struct transition {

 char etatdesti;
 char symb;
 struct transition *s;

};
struct transition *tete2,*t,*Q,*prec;
```

And here where i try to assign the address of the second list to the field p→transi;

```
 while (p!=NULL)
        {
            if (p->e==depart)
            {
                p->transi=t ;

            }
            else
            {
                p=p->etatsuiv;
            }
        }
```

and it says that there is error in this line  p->transi=t : assignment from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 0):

Because `p->transi` is a pointer to `struct etat`, while `t` is a pointer to `struct transition`.

I cannot understand your intention due to your non-English variable names but probably type of `t` should be pointer to `struct etat`

Comment: That's the point i want the pointer of struct transition point to struct etat